# Search Keywords in DataFrame by Column Value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to know if every value of one column in a dataframe have some keywords from another column. For example:

```
ITEM Column1

Item1 A       

Item1 B

Item1 C

Item2 A

Item2 B

Item2 C

Item3 A

Item3 B

Item3 D
```

I want to know for every item in the column item, if I have the values A and C from column 1. In that case, my output should be Item 1 and Item 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code will create a df with the Items that the value of `Column1` of them is A or B:

```py
filtered_df = df[df['Column1'] == A or df['Column1'] == B]
```

Now, you can select `filtered_df['ITEM']` in order to take the corresponded items. In case you just want the set of items then select `filtered_df['ITEM'].drop_duplicates()`.